# Conexion a base de datos por archivo sh

Tags: postgresql, bash, shell, environment

Tengo este archivo.sh que debo colocarle la variable de entorno de la contraseña para que una vez se ejecute automaticamente pueda realizar el proceso sin ningun problema ( es parte de un cron). E intento de todo la verdad pero no lo logro, intente añadiendo -W y mi variable, pero aun así me pide la contraseña, la contraseña en la variable viene encriptada, espero que me ayuden.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
 
if [ "$1" == "" ] || [ "$2" == "" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 [env] [dbname]"
else

OUTPUT=$(psql -h $PG_DBHOST -p 5442  -U $PGUSER  -d "$2" -a -f "$1/client/import/scripts/data_purge.sql" 2>&1)
        RETURN_CODE=$?
        echo "$OUTPUT"
 
        if [ $RETURN_CODE != 0 ]; then
                echo "Cron job failed"
                CONTEXT=$(grep -C 5 "ERROR" <<< "$OUTPUT")
                /usr/bin/perl "$1/client/import/scripts/send_cron_error_email.pl" "$1" "$0" "$CONTEXT"
        fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Si estás corriendo tu script con un cronjob, eso implica que tu exportas la variable en un lugar fuera del entorno de ejecución del cronjob.

Para hacer lo que pretendes:

1. Podrías intentar escribir esa variable en el archivo `/etc/environment`.

Por ejemplo, `echo 'PGUSER="mi contrasena 1"' >> /etc/environment`, y hacer esto sólo una vez. O en lugar de esta estrategia, solo usar un editor.

2. Otras cosa que puedes hacer, es que, dentro de tu archivo crontab (osea, ejecutando `crontab -e`) necesitas definir la variable global que quieras y luego dejar que corra.

Ejemplo de contenido de archivo crontab:

```bash
PGUSER="mi contrasena 1"

# m h dom mon dow   command
0 */5 * * *         /ruta/mi_comando.sh
```

3. En caso de que no se pueda, intenta:

```bash
# m h dom mon dow   command
0 */5 * * *         export PGUSER="mi contrasena 1"; /ruta/mi_comando.sh
```

Todas estas opciones son peligrosas si los archivos donde guardas la contraseña no son de tu usuario, sino públicas, ya que estarían guardadas en texto plano.